# Jasper server doesn't read second user attribute

Tags: web, attributes, jasperserver

I set up one attribute for the user and jasper server reads it correctly.  I add a second attribute and jasperserver reads the first, but not the second. It returns NULL!! How it is possible? How can I handle this? I needs read both the attributes of the user (COUNTRY, DEPARTMENT)

Thank you so much!!